# Get Server Name and User Mention In a invite DM

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I cant figure out how to mention a user and get the server name in a welcome DM.

Like when the bot is invited to the server it DMs the user who invited them "Hey @mention, thanks for inviting me to ServerName." I got this working with a normal welcome DM but i cant figure it out with on_guild_join.

Code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    def check(event):
        return event.target.id == bot.user.id
    bot_entry = await guild.audit_logs(action=discord.AuditLogAction.bot_add).find(check)
    await bot_entry.user.send("Hey thanks for inviting me to placeholder!")
```

I researched asked people in the python discord server i just cant figure it out. I might be dumb but i cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

As you reference guild in on_guild_join().
The name of the guild would be guild.name

Comment: How would i be able to get the user mentioned or username?

Comment: You send a DM to that user, So you can use user.name